# Sublime Text 2 - CodeIntel - Ruby Gem Completion

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, rubygems, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I was going through Ruby autocompletion for Sublime Text 2 (Mac OSx).
I've installed a cool package Sublime Codeintel that I found very usefull.

It works properly for Ruby standard library (if we can call it like that) but I cannot configure it to work with functions/classes/modules coming from Gem I've installed in my project. I've googled and I found that I need to modify the ***codeintel_language_settings*** in the Sublime Codeintel settings with something like:

```
 "Ruby": {
        "ruby": "/usr/bin/ruby",
        "rubyExtraPaths": []
    }
```

but it doesn't work. I've also tried to use the rbenv path (since I'm using rbenv) but whit no success.

Anyone could help on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this cannot be done.  It looks like an old bug, [going back to CodeIntel in Komodo](https://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=72335), and more recently it's been an [open issue on the ST2 version](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/248).

Comment: Thanks @AGS. If this cannot be done with Codeintel, would you advise to user another package? Or it doesn't exist another package that provide this functionality?

Comment: I don't know of any package/plugin that accomplishes what you are looking for.  Personally, I just use the built in popup recommendations to complete local variables.